# Shorter logs in Heroku/Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

Each line in my Heroku logs contains a verbose amount of information at the beginning:

```
2018-12-06T17:50:11.193851+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-12-06T17:50:11.193690 #4]  INFO -- : [0f0791d6-3aab-4f19-83ad-c421af4a0788] Started GET "/users/edit" for xx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2018-12-06 17:50:11 +0000
```

This makes it hard to read the logs on a small screen.

How can I shorten this to only the message itself?

```
Started GET "/users/edit" for xx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2018-12-06 17:50:11 +0000
```

Comment: That information can be useful in debugging. You never want to remove any of it. Imagine if you removed it then wanted to debug something that happened at a certain time but forgot you removed the timestamps.

Comment: My original intention wasn't to remove this information entirely – just to format it to be more readable. I was hoping there'd be a command like `heroku logs --contents-only`, although Jay's suggestions will do just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not constrained by viewing via the command line there are a number of heroku add-on tools for aggregating and viewing logs that will provide a nicer interface for viewing the logs. Most of them have a free tier and include features such as filtering, hiding columns, etc. You can find them under logging here: https://elements.heroku.com/addons

If you are limited to cli tools, you might look at [lnav](http://lnav.org/features/). At a minimum it looks like it allows you to shift the entire log over to one side or the other, along with filtering and other tools.